# Unable to import 'rest_framework'pylint(import-error)

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, pylint, django-serializer

**Unable to import rest frame work**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from EmployeeApp.models import Department, Employees

class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = ('DepartmentId',
                  'DepartmentName')

class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employees
        fields = ('EmployeesId',
                  'EmployeeName',
                  'Department',
                  'DateOfJoining',
                  'PhotoFileName')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install django-rest-framework and then add it to installed apps in settings.py

First install it using

```
pip install django-rest-framework
```

Then add it to installed apps in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework', 
]
```